# Python Twitter: name Twitter is not defined

Tags: python, twitter

I've installed the python twitter library of sixohsix (https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) and tried to connect to Twitter, but it doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twitter import *

OAUTH_TOKEN = '...'
OAUTH_SECRET = '...'
CONSUMER_KEY = '...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '...'

t = twitter.Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

# Get your "home" timeline
t.statuses.home_timeline()
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./twitter.py", line 3, in <module>
       from twitter import *
   File "/home/XXX/twitter.py", line 11, in <module>
       t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
NameError: name 'Twitter' is not defined
```

I don't know why this error occurs. I also tried

```
t = twitter.Twitter(...)
```

but it doesn't work either. I found some posts at stackOverflow, butt all solutions doesn't work.

Comment: Most likely our own file is called `twitter.py` and it gets imported instead.

Comment: What does `import twitter; print twitter.__file__` tell you? Take a look at your traceback, you named your own script `twitter` too; that is now being imported instead of the main module.

Comment: Also, there could be `python-twitter` and `twitter` packages both installed - this could cause conflicts. In that case, remove both libraries and install the one you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your traceback, I can see that your file is named `twitter.py`:

```
File "/home/XXX/twitter.py", line 11, in <module>
```

Because of this, the line `from twitter import *` is attempting to import the contents of your own script into itself, rather than the library named `twitter`, because the current directory generally has precedence over shared libraries.

Rename your own script to something that isn't identical to the library you're trying to use (e.g. `my_twitter.py`), and things will work.